# Ingress-controller localcluster

Tags: kubernetes, cluster-computing, local, kubernetes-ingress, kubernetes-service

It is possible to create ingress-controller with external-IP, on local cluster?

After many tries, I m not able to have external-IP, still status .

I already try many ingress-controllers, config maps, external deployments for cluster.

External-IP must be a public-IP or it could be internal-IP?

Thanks in any advice.

Comment: What ingress controller are you talking about? And how did you start the cluster?

Comment: Ingress-controller what you for example on GKE, loadbalancer for rest of ingresses created.External-IP of ingress than can use in DNS server as one IP, where by ingresses  assing hostname of webapps. Basic install of kubernetes cluster than assign nodes.

Comment: It is possible to set some config in control plane ? to have external-IP for cluster /

Comment: Maybe setting of kube-dns where i do not see any external-IP ?

Answer (score 0):

Already solved the problem with external-IP.

Install https://opensource.com/article/20/7/homelab-metallb.
To create pool of IPs, where load balancer can pick IP.

But now have a bigger problem, that IP addresses which come from pool, are visible only from my cluster.